# API limitation for GPS speed limit on OpenStreetMap

Tags: gps, openstreetmap, latitude-longitude

I have approached to OpenStreetMap service for scientific research purposes. In particular, I would need speed limits on various GPS points, and for this reason, I am using OpenStreetMap API. Is there a way to not get blocked if I send numerous requests all from the same terminal?

Comment: Of course. Read the [API usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/api/) and get into contact with the OSM API administrators *before* starting your bulk requests.

Comment: Crosspost: https://community.openstreetmap.org/t/api-limitation-for-gps-speed-limit/2360

Comment: If you ask a lot of data, it may be quick to download the entire database file (or continental or country) and get directly the data: they offer such files which requires a lot less resources.